# Start loading the next image once the previous has finished loading completely React

Tags: ecmascript-6

**UPDATED CODE AND QUESTION**

```
this.state.imageUrls.map((ImageUrl, index)=> {
return (<div>
    <img onLoad={this.imageLoaded} src={ImageUrl} className= 
    {this.state.galleryContent}/>
    </div>
    )})

imageLoaded = (event) => {
        this.setState({galleryContent: 'gallery-content-loaded'});
    }
```

What I am trying to do is map through an array of images. When one is loaded, call a function, which fades that image in (updating the className) then the same with all other images one by one. So the question is now once one image is loaded I am mutating data of the galleryContent, by the time the next iteration starts I need that to be set back to 'gallery-content-loading'. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Remove `()` from `this.imageLoaded()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what exactly you mean. I see you are providing imageLoaded as onLoad event. If you want to generate an array and also perform a function on it's element you better use forEach to do it by declaring another variable and append the intended div to it in each iteration of forEach. map won't offer you any callback to execute another function on element after it's equivalent mapped element is returned.